# Disable Surface Pro 4 Type Cover Fn key toggle behavior

Tags: windows, keyboard, microsoft-surface, fn-key

The Surface Pro 4 Type Cover has a "Fn" key that can be toggled on and off, which switches the behavior of the top row of keys from F-keys to utility keys like turning the volume on and off.

I use the Fn key very often while text editing (Fn+arrow keys), and I end up toggling the Fn key on and off over and over again as I'm in the midst of typing. I use the F-keys a lot as F-keys, so I'm constantly accidentally turning my volume on and off when I press alt+F4. This is really getting on my nerves.

I'd like to disable the Fn toggling feature entirely. Instead, I'd like it to stay "always on", in such a way that the F-keys always behave as F-keys, while still allowing me to use the alternate functions by pressing the F-keys while holding down Fn. Is this possible? Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe that exactly what you're asking for is currently possible, no. I found some discussion and suggestions in [this thread](http://forums.windowscentral.com/microsoft-surface-book/402737-any-way-keep-fn-key-enabled.html) (along with many people who did not understand the question!) which may help you solve your underlying problem in other ways though.

One suggestion there was to use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) to map the F keys permanently to their desired functions - `F1` for Help, `F5` for Refresh etc. I haven't done this myself, but have used AHK before and recall it being fairly straightforward.

However, probably the easiest solution is to either:

- Buy an earlier Type Cover (from a Surface Pro 3 for example), where the `Fn` key required you to also press `Caps Lock` to toggle between the two behaviours, making an accidental toggling almost impossible (unless you play your keyboard like a grand piano!) or at least much less likely.
- Alternatively, you could get an inexpensive USB/Bluetooth keyboard which doesn't have the `Fn` toggle functionality at all and use that instead of the Type Cover.

Comment: I really wish Microsoft would come up with an official solution for this. :/

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot yes, I agree. I was hoping someone else would answer with good news for you - it's not often I hope my answer is wrong!

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot Me too, hope they give an option.

Comment: Super irritating! I have to look under my hand to know what keypress is going to happen.

Answer (score 3):

At least on Surface Pro 3 if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd> you will toggle the default state of the keys between hotkeys and the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys.

Comment: This was suggested years ago, and the OP reported that it did not work as desired:  “If I press Fn+CapsLock then press Fn again, it still toggles the Fn mode.  I want it to stay always on even if I press the Fn key.”

Answer (score -1):

Fn/Caps will disable the button.

MR

Comment: If you mean (Fn) + (Caps Lock), this was suggested years ago, and the OP reported that it did not work as desired.